# Расчет нагрузки NFS сервера

Tags: debian, tcp, nfs, mtu

Машина на Debian Stretch является бэкап сервером для 2х PostgreSQL, 2х KVM, 1x Samba, Webhost отдельных серверов общим обобьем 40TB.

Бэкап сервер раздает точки монтирования каждому из серверов в отдельности по LAN 1GB/s. Резервное копирование инкрементальное на базе **rsnapshot** на стороне каждого из серверов.

Как можно посчитать нагрузку на бэкап сервер, что оптимизировать в настройках NFS?

текущие настройки

```
/export/path/server-1/backup server-1(rw,no_root_sqash,async)
/export/path/server-2/backup server-2(rw,no_root_sqash,async)
/export/path/server-3/backup server-3(rw,no_root_sqash,async)
...
```

Comment: В сеть упрётесь и всего делов. Для бекап хоста не имеет смысла что-то ещё крутить. Проверьте лучше мониторинг, что вы, например, заметите что бекапы завершаются ошибкой. А лучше настройте автоматическую проверку, что вы можете из бекапа восстановиться.